# prove that if the poset L has a least element, then that element is unique.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I am trying to work through this question to study for Discrete Structures 2 but I am struggling as I am new to the concept of least upper bound and greatest lower bound if someone could please prove this and elaborate by explaining the proof.

Comment: Suppose otherwise that there are two distinct least elements...

Comment: Assume $a,b$ are least elements, then use the antisymmetry of the relation to prove that they are equal.

Comment: Since you mention being new to the concepts of least upper bound and greatest lower bound, it might be useful to notice that neither of these concepts is involved in the question. You need only the simpler concept of least element.

Comment: It might help you to write out the definition of "least element".

Answer (score 2):

The least element (if it exists) is precisely the supremum of $\emptyset$: indeed, the supremum of $\emptyset$ (if it exists) is an element $x$ of the poset such that:

- $x$ is greater than or equal to every member of $\emptyset$ - this is true for all $x$!
- whenever $y$ is greater than or equal to every member of $\emptyset$ (that is, whenever $y$ is in the poset), we have $x \leq y$.

More simply put, it is an element $x$ of the poset such that for every element $y$, we have $x \leq y$. But that's exactly what it means for $x$ to be the least element of the poset.

So it's enough to prove the more general (and more useful) fact that the supremum of a subset $A$ of the poset is unique, if it exists.

---

To do this, let $x$ and $y$ both be suprema of $A$; we aim to show $x=y$. What do we know?

- $x$ and $y$ are both upper bounds for $A$;
- whenever $z$ is an upper bound for $A$, we have $x \leq z$ (since $x$ is a *least* upper bound for $A$)
- whenever $z$ is an upper bound for $A$, we have $y \leq z$ (since $y$ is a *least* upper bound for $A$)

Given these facts, there's basically only two deductions we can make:

- we have $x \leq y$ (deduced from the second bullet point, letting $z=y$)
- we have $y \leq x$ (deduced from the third bullet point, letting $z=x$)

By antisymmetry (since we're in a poset), then $x=y$.